# There is a Python problem with the kivy library

Tags: python, pip, kivy, modulenotfounderror

I wanted to install kivy but I have a problem: Error while finding module specification for 'kivy.examples.**main**' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy.examples').

To fix the problem, I tried to enter : `pip install kivy-examples`

It didn't work for me, so I tried to enter: `python -m kivy.examples.demo`

Then: `python -m kivy.examples.__main__`

but it didn't help me.                                                                                                         .

Answer (score 0):

"kivy-examples" is not a module, it's a collection of programs. After running `pip install kivy-examples` in my virtual environment I found the collection in `venv/share/kivy-examples/` directory. So you cannot import or run them as `kivy.examples`. Instead change dir to subdirectories under `venv/share/kivy-examples/`, find out application file (often but not always it's `main.py`) and run it like `python main.py`.